# Fingerprint Sensor 04f3:0c03

Tags: 19.04, fingerprint-reader

I have this fingerprint sensor which is returned by lsusb: 04f3:0c03. The website of fprintd says this is supported in the latest dev. Now, Ubuntu 19.04 won't recognize it and on the pages they say, the packages on 18.04 and later are up2date. What can I do?

Thanks, Uwe.

Comment: Did you check your BIOS/UEFI settings? The fingerprint sensor may have to be enabled there.

Comment: It works in win10.